# When I use the pow(base, exponent) function in C++ and the exponent is a fraction, I always get 1 as output

Tags: c++, pow, cmath

I want to calculate the root of a number, so in the function pow(base, exponent) I put 4 as base and 1/2 as exponent.

If I use 0.5 instead of 1/2 I get the correct result, 2.

I don't want to use the sqrt() function because I need to ask the user for the denominator of the fraction.

Here is my code:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    cout<< pow(4, (1/2));
}
```

`

The problem is that when I run the code I get 1. Always, with any number.

Comment: `std::cout << (1/2) << '\n';`

Comment: `pow(x, 0)` is 1.

Comment: Use correct type: `1. / 2.`

Comment: Don't mix integers and floating point and don't use pow for integers. (just use repeated multiplication).  and also unlearn `using namespace std;`. `4` is an integer, `4.0f` is a float and `4.` or `4.0` is a double.